# Web app: detect identity of the host workstation running a VDI

Tags: web-applications, vdi

We have an enterprise-level web application deployed at 100+ sites, each with hundreds or even thousands of users and workstations. Many of our clients are now looking to move to virtual desktops, and this is causing problems as some of the application's services are location-contextual.

Is there a way to determine which *physical* workstation a request came from?

We support various ages of back-end servers, all Microsoft, from 2008 (pre-R2) onwards. Most sites use IE8, although they're slowly migrating upwards, and the applications themselves work just fine in IE10 and Edge. The newer iterations of the product are standards-driven (HTML5/CSS3), and run nicely on most modern browsers.

Client-side scripting as a solution would probably be OK - as with any modern web-app, there's lots of that already - but everything I've researched leads me to believe that there's nothing you can do to reach outside the VDI boundaries and discover where you are in the real world. It appears to be a massive challenge for native desktop apps, let alone something sandboxed by the browser.

I'd love to be more specific and give lots of details, but by definition things are kinda vague here. We have no control over which virtualisation infrastructure our clients will implement, although we may have an opportunity to advise them on recommended configurations. Quick straw-poll shows that Citrix and VMWare are popular. Also, I'm the development team's manager, and therefore don't know anything of value in the technical world :).

Comment: I'd be happy to hear some opinions on this. Have you gotten any direction so far?